# round() mode ROUND_HALF_UP with PHP 5.2.17

Tags: php, rounding

I have a static variable **between 200 and 500,**

and, if the value between 300 and 350, I have to round  the nearest half point to enter table. 
I tried to divide it and use the php 5.4 round() ROUND_HALF_UP, but the version is not available for this function.

```
$var = 320;
```

**so, i couldnt find except this poor solution,**

```
function ChecktheValue($val) {

if (($val > 200 && $val < 250)) { $value = 250; } 
.
.
.
if (($val > 450 && $val < 500)) { $value = 500; } 
return $value;
}
```

so this is not a solution exactly. 
**any idea?**

Comment: `ceil()` is the equivalent of `ROUND_HALF_UP`. But that by itself hardly does anything useful in your case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

... learn math:

```
$val = intval($var / 50)*50+50;
```

Comment: thanks for the advice, i will try. but how about the value is int? try with the 350, 450, 250 values, and what returns.

Comment: 450 / 50 = 9; 9 * 50 = 450; 450 + 50 = 500; According to the given rule above `if (($val > 450 && $val < 500)) { $value = 500; }` and the rule (assumed) `if (($val > 400 && $val < 450)) { $value = 400; }` this result is right since your cascading if's will not cover this.